# jQuery dataTables - Clear search on a column

Tags: filtering, datatables

Looking at this example, http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html, which uses columns.search() from the DataTable API, how would you 'clear' the search and show all results again when the user selects 'All' or the empty first option?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You clear the search by using an empty string as search term, without regular expression match. The individual column filtering demo is somehow a little bit misleading, since the first (unnamed) option not is "all" or "any", as one could belive, but in fact should be named "empty" or "null". If you select the first option, a regular expression search for the empty string is performed. I guess the demo is made in haste.

Modified demo where selecting the first option "clear" the search, that is selecting all :

```js
$("#example tfoot th").each( function ( i ) {
  var select = $('<select><option value="">All</option></select>')
    .appendTo( $(this).empty() )
    .on( 'change', function () {
       var term =  $(this).val()!='' ? '^'+$(this).val()+'$' : '';
       table.column( i )
          .search(term, true, false )
          .draw();
       } );

  table.column( i ).data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
    select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
  });
});
```

modified individual column filtering demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/CmMfJ/**

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this would help in that example, but a way I found for clearing the individual column search textfields is like so:

First this is how I create the fields:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
    $('#myTable tfoot th').each( function () {
        var title = $('#myTable thead th').eq( $(this).index() ).text();
        $(this).html( '<input id="'+title.replace(/ /g,'')+'_search" type="text" placeholder="'+title+'" />' );
    } );

    oTable = $('#myTable').DataTable({ settings bla bal });

    // Apply the search
    oTable.columns().eq( 0 ).each( function ( colIdx ) {
        $( 'input', oTable.column( colIdx ).footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {

            oTable
                .column( colIdx )
                .search( this.value, true )
                .draw();
        } );
    } );
}
```

And this I how I clear them:

```
function fnResetAllFilters() {
    // Apply blank string
    oTable.columns().eq( 0 ).each( function ( colIdx ) {
            $( 'input', oTable.column( colIdx ).footer() ).val(''); //clear column visible text
            oTable.columns(colIdx).search( '', true ); //clear dataTable column search filters
        }
    )
    oTable.search( '', true ).draw(); //clears global search filter then finally draw the table, all done..
}
```

Notice the similarities between the block "//Apply the search" and the function fnResetAllFilters().

Answer (score 1):

There's a simple way, given by the author.

Just call like this in your clear event:

```
$('#datatable tfoot input').val('').change();
```

As datatables use the events to send commands to server, it'll also clear the search!

Answer (score 0):

I figured a very simple way to do it.

1. Clear all text from text inputs
2. Trigger a change event to all text inputs

Since DataTables uses change event to perform the filtering, you just have to trigger one for it to redraw the table.

```
function clearAllInputs() {
      // Will reset all input text values to nothing.
      $("input:text").val('');
      // Will trigger a "change" event in order for datatables to refresh the filtering. This is because DataTables uses the change event to perform filtering.
      $("input:text").trigger("change");
    }
```

This should also work for specific filter input text. You just have to select it correctly with jquery!

Hope it will help!